# Gmail push notification error (Only one user push notification client allowed per developer)

Tags: gmail, gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub

I tried to execute gmail api's watch on my two gmail accounts and it works fine.

But when the other user tried to do so, it shows this error:

> HTTP error 400 : "Only one user push notification client allowed per developer (call /stop then try again)">

I don't know if the problem is on the pub/sub client configuration or doing stop and watch will resolve the problem?

Can someone explain the meaning of this statement "Only one user push notification client allowed per developer"?

Comment: It sounds like each "registered" app can only be running one connection to Gmail. Maybe try creating another [client key](https://console.developers.google.com).

Comment: Your question doesn't really contain enough detailed technical info. What do you mean by "I tried to execute gmail api's watch on my two gmail accounts and it works fine"? What do you mean by "But when the other user tried to do so"?

Comment: I've got same error recently, so I've decided before executing /watch to renew subscription, to call /stop first (just in case) https://stackoverflow.com/a/45019396/771379

Comment: It might be because you are sending too many requests to `users.watch`. Gmail's documentation recommends to rewatch a mailbox once every day. If you call `users.watch` too frequently, you might get that error.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a different project for the Cloud Pub/Sub topic that the other user wants to set up a Gmail API watch on.

Answer (score 1):

You can always renew a watch by first stopping the watch and then immediately initiating a new watch right after. So, try to use users.stop once before you use users.watch.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar issue. Although this might not be helpful to the OP, for me the solution was to abandon Google's Pub/Sub and use IMAP IDLE instead, which is much better suited for OP's use case of monitoring several inboxes.