# watch request to new topic pauses push notifications to existing topic

Tags: gmail-api

I've configured two topics in my Google Cloud Pub/Sub account, each with a single subscription, under a single project.

When I call watch() on my inbox, passing topic 1 to the watch request, I receive push notifications to my desired endpoint. When I call watch() on my inbox for *topic 2*, I receive push notifications for the endpoint tied to topic 2, but **push notifications stop arriving for topic 1**.

It appears that only a single topic can push out notifications for a given inbox at any given time, for a given project. Can anyone help confirm whether this is the case?

I can't find anything in [the documentation for Gmail push notifications](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push) that notes this limitation. I receive a successful response from the API every time I call watch() again (subscribed to topic 1 -> call watch() for topic 2, and vice versa), but notifications still stop for the topic I was previously subscribed to. I'm also well within the expiry window for the watch() requests.

Any advice / direction would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each developer can only have one watch setup on a given mailbox.  It's not specified explicitly but the API call says the watch() call is for either setting up or updating the watch: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/watch
(there's no "List Watches", "watch.id" unique identifier, etc that would be required in REST for multiple watches to be allowed.  A watch is a singleton resource.)

Comment: Cool, appreciate the response, Eric.

Comment: Eric, any plans to support pushing for multiple topics? Also when post a watch request with a new topic, do subscribers of the old topic get notified of the subscription cancelation? Thanks