# Calling watch a second time on a different PubSub and client ID cancels the previous one

Tags: gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub

We are developing an app that uses the Gmail API to synchronize the e-mails of our users. We are relying on `watch` to get change notifications through  a PubSub, as recommended in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push).

Everything is okay, and we are receiving the notifications correctly.

However, as many software companies, we do have a **staging environment** to test our new features. We have a staging Google OAuth2 client with **different Client ID / Client Secret** to authenticate to Google, and a **staging PubSub topic/subscription** to receive notifications.

If I connect my Gmail account on the staging environment, everything works fine. I receive the notifications in staging. If I connect after that the same Gmail account on the production environment, I receive the notifications in production ; **but** the staging notifications stops coming. The same happens the other way round.

I thought that by using a different client and a different PubSub, we could get the notifications in both environments. It doesn't seem the case. Maybe Google limits the subscription per Google Cloud project?

Does anyone have already met this limitation or have more information about this?

Best regards,

François Voron

Comment: As stated in this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45019396/5995040), it is an expected behavior. "Each developer can only have one watch setup on a given mailbox."

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Mr.Rebot! However, I setup a watch on two different Google clients (a staging and production one), with different client id/client secret. It's the same as having Company A and Company B synchronizing my mails ; that's why this behaviour is quite unexpected.